# POST multiple files with -d in curl

Tags: bash, curl

I'm using curl to create several classifications. I have written the json for the many classifications and they are in one folder. I would like to create all the classifications in one go. But using curl I can only create them one at a time. How could I make them in one request?

```
curl -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @pii.json  http://127.0.0.1:21000/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs
```

The curl manual for -d says 'Multiple files can also be specified'. How can I do this? All my attempts have failed.

Do I need a bash script instead? If so, could you help me - I'm not a coder and I'm struggling without an example!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to use multiple `-d` with JSON data since curl concatenates multiple ones with a `&` in between. As described in the man page for -d/--data:

> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command
>   line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a
>   separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would
>   generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.

You can however easily and conveniently pass several files on stdin to let curl use them all in one go:

```
cat a.json b.json c.json | curl -d@- -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:21000/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs
```

(please note that `-X POST` has no place on a command line that uses -d)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. When I use this only the one classification is created from the first json file. The rest are ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid that's more of an issue of what exact JSON contents you're sending rather than how you use curl - I think.

Comment: using multiple `-d` only works with `--next` with repeating url and headers too.Is there any way to reuse tcp connection to same url, same headers and send multiple post body?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following to work in the end:

```
<fileToUpload.dat xargs -I %  curl -X POST -T "{%}" -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:21000/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs
```

Where fileToUpload.dat contained a list of the .json files.

This seemed to work over Daniel's answer, probably due to the contents of the files. Hopefully this is useful to others if Daniel's solution doesn't work for them.

Comment: THIS! This works wonderful... I modified this to upload an entire directory of documentation to my Nexus RAW repository. 

    find docs/ | xargs -I % curl -X POST -T "{%}" -u admin:admin https://nexus.mycompany.com/repositories/docs/some/path/

Answer (score 0):

I needed to upload all the *.json files from a folder via curl and I made this little script.

```
nfiles=*.json
echo "Enter user:"
read user
echo "Enter password:"
read -s password
for file in $nfiles
do
    echo -e "\n----$file----"
    curl --user $user:$password -i -X POST "https://foo.bar/foo/bar" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@$file"
done
```

Maybe fits your needs.