# Submit multiple json payloads with curl

Tags: bash, curl

I am working with the confluent kafka, zookeeper in docker. I successfully submit a json file to kafka topic then consume as follow

```
 curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"name": "quickstart-file-source", "config {"connector.class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector", "tasks.max":"1", "topic":"quickstart-data", "file": "/tmp/quickstart/input.json"}}' \
http://localhost:28081/connectors
```

Above curl command has only one json file which executes successfully but I need to post multiple json files. Is there any way to do it?

Here is my kafka connect

```
docker run -d \
  --name=kafka-connect-avro \
  --net=host \
  -e CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=localhost:29091 \
  -e CONNECT_REST_PORT=28081 \
  -e CONNECT_GROUP_ID="quickstart-avro" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-avro-config" \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-avro-offsets" \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-avro-status" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="localhost" \
  -e CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG \
  -v /tmp/quickstart/file:/tmp/quickstart \
  confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest
```

[Reference link](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.1/cp-docker-images/docs/quickstart.html?source=post_page-----a8f447cac028----------------------)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make individual JSON files in the current directory and post them separately in a loop

e.g.

```
$ ls *.json  # list your connectors
payload1.json
payload2.json
```

And then loop over them

```
for f in `ls *.json`; do 
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data@${f} http://localhost:28081/connectors
done
```

[Or simpler to use `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101392/2308683)

Comment: exactly. i have multiple json file in a directory. can you please comment curl command with above forloop   which is in mys question

Comment: My curl is the same as your question, just using a file rather than a JSON string

Comment: got it i will try it first .and let you konw thanks buddy

Comment: sure it can: `cat *.json | curl -d@- -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:28081/connectors`

Comment: @DanielStenberg News to me ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101392